# Empty values in a Python list

Tags: python, list

Is it possible to assign a list with empty values in Python?
This is possible:

```
x = []
```

But I want to do something like:

```
x = [4,7,2, ,8,9,1]
```

with an empty value inside.
The reason is that I have a large number of lists with 7 values and sometimes one of the values are unavailable. I need to keep say 8 as x[4],9 as x[5] etc.

My thoughts:
Maybe I should just put a number like 999 inside, or a string "empty" and tell my code to ignore 999 or "empty" or whatever.

What is the best option here?

Comment: You seem to be using the list as proxy for a mapping of integer keys, rather than as an ordered sequence. Consider using a dictionary `{ 0: 4, 1: 7, 2: 2, 4: 8, 5: 9, 6: 1}` instead.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `None` for the "empty" value.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [11,22,None,44,55]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option other than using `None` is to use some other unique object such as `empty = object()` as this allows `None` to be used as a list item and then test if the list item is empty via `l[x] is empty`.

Answer (score 1):

Use "None". It indicates that there is no value.

Comment: how is this different to rusticbit's answer?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that there was an answer already when I put mine.