# Update Postgres String column value without start and end double quotes

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, alembic

In User table the column `description` column is a string.

But while update that column with empty string `''` using sqlalchemy alembic, It will be saved as `""`.

```
  for row in sa_session.query(Modelpackage):
            setattr(row, 'description', '')
```

Is there any way to saved it without double quotes `""` ?

**Actual Result:-**

[image]

**Expected Result:-**

[image]

Comment: How sure are you about these double quotes " ? How did you check for these quotes? Many tools display some quotes when there is no content. SELECT length(description) FROM _table; -- should be 0

Comment: @FrankHeikens I checked in the postgressDB, Seems It's saved it as "". instead of empty.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I used DBeaver

Comment: That tells you something about DBeaver, not about the database nor the data inside that database. Please check the length of the content, that should be zero when you put an empty string in the table.

Comment: SqlAlchemy is a Python based app, so try to put setattr(row, 'description', None). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219734/empty-values-in-a-python-list

Comment: @FrankHeikens I understood, But the problem is, If I want to save "test string" it should be saved without double quotes.

Comment: @Jesusbrother I tried it with setattr() but same result.

Comment: This is something a tool in your tool chain is doing as `insert into some_table values('')` will not result in `""` being saved. Something above the database is doing `'""'` to get this.

Comment: @Jesusbrother passing `None` would insert `NULL` values, which are not the same as an empty string.

Comment: @snakecharmerb you are right. I forgot that in Python None is used as an alternative of Null

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. [This code](https://pastebin.com/79yNjCyP) works properly for me.