# How can I insert EMPTY values in python's list?

Tags: python, list

Here, I have the list `test_list=[1,2,3,0,5]`.

I want to change the list which contains empty values, like `[1,2,3, ,5]`

All the way I found is to add `None` or `np.nan` or just `''`.

But all those values are not working at my case, cause I just need to leave the place empty. how can I create it? The reason I need it is to put those values into `scipy`'s interpolation.

Comment: When you say empty, do you mean uninitialized? This question depends on your definition of "empty".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Empty values in a Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219734/empty-values-in-a-python-list)

Comment: Why do you not want to use `None`?

Comment: Umm.. maybe yes. I just need the list which will be printed as [1, 2, 3, ,5] in this format...

Comment: Do you just want the list to be printed as `[1, 2, 3, ,5]`?

Comment: I will put those values into scipy.interpolate library. It seems like this library is not reading "None" as none value. So, I want to get it just empty.
Which means...
1. Former Q&A is not fit in this question, because I already tried None..

Comment: Yes exactly! That is what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Umm.. maybe yes. I just need the list which will be printed as [1, 2, 3, ,5] in this format...

You can define a class with a `repr()` of the empty string:

```py
>>> class Nothing:
...     def __repr__(self):
...             return ''
... 
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, Nothing(), 5]
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, , 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just "not have" a value in a list, a list is defined by its items. You could use `None` which is Python's representation of "nothing" or `[]`.

[Empty values in a Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219734/empty-values-in-a-python-list)

If you just want to print an array and ignore `None` values you can make a function.

```py
numbers = [1,2,3,4,None,5,6,7,8,9,10]

def print_list(input_list):
    printstr = "["

    for item in input_list:
        item = item if item else ""
        printstr += str(item) + ","
    
    printstr += "]"

    print(printstr)

print_list(numbers)

# prints [1,2,3,4,,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```